# Recursive method for loan calculation

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive method that takes 3 parameters (a loan amount, an interest rate, and a monthly payment). The interest is compounded monthly. The goal is to find out how many months it will take to pay off the loan completely. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    public static double loanLength(double loan, double interest, double payment) {
    if (payment > loan + loan * interest) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        double completeLoan = loan + (loan * interest);
        double stillOwe = completeLoan - payment;
        if (stillOwe <= 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 1 + (loanLength(stillOwe, interest, payment));
        }

    }
```

Examples of EXPECTED returns include:

**loanLength(1000, 0.10, 200) is paid off in 6 months**

**loanLength(0, 0.90, 50) is 0 months**

But my returns look like:

**loanLength(1000, 0.10, 200): 7 months**

**loanLength(0, 0.90, 50): 0 months**

My second test works fine, but my first one is just 1 integer above what it should be. I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's the best case for recursion. A loop would be much easier to read (and write). Skipping the fact that this calculation can be done in a single expression. Is it just an exercise to practice recursion?

Comment: Naming your parameters will make the code readable!!!!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It's meant to be done recursively for practice. I could easily do it in a loop form, but I'm definitely struggling with recursion.

Comment: @Andreas Done, my apologies.

Comment: `stillOwe` can never be < 0.

Comment: 2 Errors: 1) The first `if` statement should be `if (loan <= 0) return 0;`. 2) If you expect 6 as result, then your interest rate of 10% is too high for a per-month interest. It's likely the APR, so you need to divide by 12: `completeLoan = loan + loan * interest / 12`.

Comment: Can OP clarify whether `0.10` represents 10% APR or 0.1% APR?

Comment: @JeremyWest The `0.10` represents a 10% interest rate; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int loanLength(double loan, double interestAPR, double payment) {
    if (loan <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    double monthlyInterest = interestAPR / (12 * 100);
    double compounded = loan * (1 + monthlyInterest);
    return 1 + loanLength(compounded - payment, interestAPR, payment);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(loanLength(0, 0.90, 50)); // 0
    System.out.println(loanLength(1000, 10.0, 200)); // 6
    System.out.println(loanLength(1000, 0.1, 200)); // 6 (FWIW)
}
```

Please note that interest APR is expressed *as is*, i.e. a $10,000 loan at 10% APR and $500 monthly payments is calculated as

```
loanLength(10000, 10.0, 500);
```

If `0.10` = 10% APR, then change this line

```
double monthlyInterest = interestAPR / 12;
```

Comment: Good job, i've been trying to code it myself, this is very good

Comment: Why are you also dividing by 100? It looks like his input is already expressed decimal... 0.10 = 10% APR?

Comment: @JeremyWest - because that is the [conversion rate](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-annual-interest-rate-monthly-rate-1822.html)

Comment: No, that is only the conversion rate if the rate is expressed as a percentage. In other words, if the input to `interestAPR` is 10.0 representing a 10% annual percentage rate, then your code is correct. But if the input is 0.10 representing the same 10% annual percentage rate, your code is incorrect. I'm assuming from his sample inputs that 0.10 is meant to represent 10% APR rather than 0.1% APR, although I could be wrong?

Comment: @JeremyWest - Yes, this method assumes you input the percent as a decimal, i.e. 0.10 = 10%. It's not the fault of the method to know whether its input is in percent or decimal; it is user-input error if a wrong result is returned. Regardless, it's an easy change.

Comment: No, that's exactly my concern. Your method is correct if the value `10` is passed in to represent 10%. If the user inputs 0.1, that is, the APR expressed as a decimal, then it should not be divided by 100. This is apparent even from the article you cited.

Comment: @JeremyWest - Ahh, yes, I misspoke that first sentence. Personally, I prefer `10.0` = 10% APR because that's how banks list it and no mental math is required. Therefore, not editing and not understanding the downvote.

Comment: The downvote is because your earlier comment contradicts your most recent comment and your latest comment seems to contradict the sample input. You also haven't clarified in your solution what input you expect. If you want me to remove the downvote and upvote, you should at least clarify.